# Enabling Apps For Office in Microsoft Word 2013

Tags: ms-word, windows-store-apps, visio

I am working to import a visio diagram from a vsdx file which has multiple pages, and it seems there is an app on the office store site to help me with this. Problem is Office Apps is currently disabled in my install of Office Word 2013. How do I enable this please so my apps can load? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution:

1)Click file to get to the backstage menu.

2)Then click options

3)Then click trust center

4)Bottom right is trust center options

5)Then click trusted app catalogs on the left selection pane.

6)Look at the check boxes and see if any of those are checked. If so un-check.

Comment: I did just that but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Insert->Text->Object->Create from File to import your Visio diagram. The imported object can only display one page at a time, however, but you can double click it to edit and display it in an embed Visio window.

I think the more general approach is export your diagram to some graphic formats and insert to the document. When you make change to the diagram, just export it again, go back to Word, right click on the image and Change picture.

Comment: I of course want to allow the option of editing the diagrams in the future.That is  why I would rather have them imported directly from Visio.

Comment: With the first option you can edit the diagram in the future (in Word via an embed but full features Visio window). If you want to edit the diagram in Visio and have it automatically reflects in Word, select the check box Link to file in the insert object dialog.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably late, but I had the same problem. What worked for me was going to File in Word and converting the format to a newer format. It had been running in Compatibility Mode because the file I opened in Word 2013 was actually created on Word 2002. So I had to convert it to the 2013 updated format, then save the file after converting, and then the Apps button was enabled! Presto! I hope this helps anyone who comes across the problem. I had NO clue what to do until I read online somewhere.